# Is there a way to define starred variants for a keyvalue system?

Tags: pgfkeys, starred-version, key-value

I've created an environment for which various parameters are set through key values.  Instead of creating a hornet's nest of various booleans, I would just like to have a slight variant form for some of the keys to handle some of the formatting.

In particular, while none of the keys are mandatory,  I need a way of handling things if I omit some of the keys.  So, I figured I'd create starred variants.

To help you understand what I'm trying to do in the following MWE, here's the basic idea:  I have three optional *tags* to add to a quote (`title`, `description`, and `author`).  Each is meant to show up on its own line, when used.  If the key is not used, then nothing should be done.  But if the `author` key is not called, then I need a means of handling the line breaks to avoid unwanted extra whitespace.  The starred variants are to be used in such a situation.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
%%----------
\makeatletter
%%----------
\let\ae@source@title\relax
\let\ae@source@description\relax
\let\ae@source@author\relax
%%----------
\newlength{\widthofwidestline}
\newlength{\afterEpigraphSkip}
\setlength{\widthofwidestline}{3in}
\setlength{\afterEpigraphSkip}{1\baselineskip}
%%----------
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/my/epigraph/environment/set/options/.cd,
    title/.code         = {\def\ae@source@title{#1\\}},
    description/.code   = {\def\ae@source@description{#1\\}},
    author/.code        = {\def\ae@source@author{#1}},
%% variants for handling `title` and `description` when `author`
%% (and possibly other keys) are missing.
    title*/.code         = {\def\ae@source@title{#1}},
    description*/.code   = {\def\ae@source@description{#1}},
%% length parameters
    longest line/.code  = {\settowidth{\widthofwidestline}{#1}},
    afterskip/.code     = {\setlength{\afterEpigraphSkip}{#1}},
  }
\newenvironment{epigraph}[1]
  {\pgfkeys{ /ae/my/epigraph/environment/set/options/.cd, #1 }%
   \par\hspace*{\fill}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\widthofwidestline+1em}%
  }
  {\attrib{%
     \ae@source@title
     \ae@source@description
     \ae@source@author
     \makebox[0pt][r]{\rule[-0.8pt]{1in}{0.4pt}}%
    }%
   \end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\fill}%
   \vspace{\afterEpigraphSkip}%
  }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{epigraph}{title={title},
                 description={description},
                 author={me},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 1
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{author={me},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 2
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{title={title},
                 description={description},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 3
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{title={title},
                 description*={description},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 4
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{title*={title},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 5
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{description*={description},
                 longest line=abcdefghijklm}
  Scenario 6
\end{epigraph}

\end{document}
```

`Scenario 3` illustrates what I want to avoid.  This MWE produces:

[image]

I'm not so much interested in creating a new epigraph command:  I know there are such packages.  I also know that I could set and process booleans to handle this issue *automatically*.  But as I mentioned, I really would like to avoid creating boolean switches.

I'm more interested in a larger issue where key values are being used, but where occasionally you might want to handle some of the keys in a slightly different manner than *usual:*  hence the starred-variant.

I haven't found anything in the documentation that would allow for this.  I also didn't find anything on this site related to starred variants of keys.

I'm primarily interested in feedback about best practices in such a situation.

Comment: You could define `title/.style={title*={#1\\}}`. By the way, is there a reason you use `.code` handlers that simply define a macro? You could just use an actual value-key (handler: `.initial`) and reduce the overhead.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don't think I understand how your `.style` method would work.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm very new to using key-values.  It seemed to me that I was doing more than just defining a value, but also setting up additional formatting.  Hence the use of `.code`.  If you could illustrate how to avoid making so many calls via `.code`, I'd be very interested.  After all, I'm more interested in best practices here than just some hack that gets the job done.

Comment: The only difference between `title` and `title*` that I see is that the un-starred version includes a final ``\\``. If you define `title` as a key that simply forwards its argument appended by ``\\`` to `title*`. On the other hand, I would actually post-process the values so that the user doesn’t need to work so much; of course, this would involve some checking for empty values and is probably depending on how complex the input scenarios can get.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel With regard to the `title` key, are you suggesting something more along the lines of `title*/.initial=#1,` followed by `title/.style={title*={#1\\}}`?

Comment: No, simply `title*/.initial=` sets the value to an empty string. The `.style` itself implies one argument. Though, as I said, I’d check for empty values as egreg did but with `pgfkeys`, of course.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'd be interested in seeing how you would test for empty values with `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using actual value-keys. These are setup with the `.initial` handler (every value has an initial value). This reduces overhead, in my opinion. As it just a wrapper for a `\csname` solution. A key of the path `/tree/sub/name` is stored in the macro `\pgfk@/tree/sub/name`. I don't see much of the reason why I'd define a key that simply sets another family of macros.

The macros starting with `\@epi@…` in the environment are merely temporarily macros since they are only defined in the environment (which groups its content).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
%%----------
\makeatletter
%%----------
\newlength{\widthofwidestline}
\newlength{\afterEpigraphSkip}
\setlength{\widthofwidestline}{3in}
%%----------
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
\def\epigraphset{\pgfqkeys{/ae/my/epigraph/environment/set/options}}
\def\epigraphgetvalue#1{\pgfkeysgetvalue{/ae/my/epigraph/environment/set/options/#1}}
\epigraphset{
    title/.initial      =,
    description/.initial=,
    author/.initial     =,
    longest line/.code  = {\settowidth{\widthofwidestline}{#1}},
    afterskip/.code     = {\setlength{\afterEpigraphSkip}{#1}},
    afterskip=1\baselineskip
  }
\newenvironment{epigraph}[1]{
  \epigraphset{#1}%
  \par\hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\widthofwidestline+1em}%
}{
  \attrib{%
     \epigraphgetvalue{title}\@epi@title
     \epigraphgetvalue{description}\@epi@desc
     \epigraphgetvalue{author}\@epi@author
%     \noindent % needed (?) if you use \\
     \@epi@title
     \ifx\@epi@desc\pgfkeys@empty\else
       \par\@epi@desc
     \fi
     \ifx\@epi@author\pgfkeys@empty\else
       \par\@epi@author
     \fi
     \makebox[0pt][r]{\rule[-0.8pt]{1in}{0.4pt}}%
  }%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \vspace{\afterEpigraphSkip}%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\epigraphset{longest line=abcdefghijklm}
\begin{epigraph}{title=title,description=description,author=me}
  TDA
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{author=me}
  \_\_A
\end{epigraph}
\begin{epigraph}{description=description}
  \_D\_
\end{epigraph}
\begin{epigraph}{title=title}
  T\_\_
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}{title=title,description=description}
  TD\_
\end{epigraph}
\begin{epigraph}{title=title,author=author}
  T\_A
\end{epigraph}
\begin{epigraph}{description=description,author=author}
  \_DA
\end{epigraph}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  This helps me understand quite a few details about `pgfkeys` that were murky to me at best.  But I do still have another question.  According to my understanding of `pgfkeysgetvaule{<key>}{<macro>}`---as explained in the manual---I would have attempted to run a test as `\ifx\@epi@title\relax\else....\fi`.  But this is clearly wrong (it doesn't work when I try it!).  How do I reconcile what the manual says about the `macro` being set to `\relax` when the `\ifx<macro>\relax` will not test correctly?  Why would I know that I should resort to testing against `\@empty`?

Comment: Oh.  Maybe I know the answer to my latest question:  it's because `pgfkeys` is doing something like `\def<macro>{\relax}` and `\@empty` is defined as `\def\@empty{\relax}`.  So the meaning of the two macros is the same.  Where as the meaning of `\relax` is not the meaning of `\<macro>` when defined to be `\relax`.  Right?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\@empty` means literally empty: `\def\@empty{}`. And this also true for the value-key (which is `\def`ed into the special `pgfk@/…` macro). The `\pgfkeysgetvalue` macro `\let`s the second argument to the `\pgfk@/…` macro, basically `\let\@epi@title\pgfk@/ae/…/title`. Thus `\@epi@title` is as it would have been defined as `\def\@epi@title{}` and can now compared to `\@empty`. That has nothing to do with `\relax`.

Comment: So, what is the `pgf` manual talking about when it says that the macro will be equal to `\relax`? [see page 786 of the manual---I have the 2.10 CVS version.]

Comment: @A.Ellett *If the key has not been set* excludes setting the key with `.initial`. There is no value-key that is not set. (This is just TeX: `\csname`ing an undefined macro name expands to `\relax`.) If the key has not been set by the user it simply has the value of its `.initial`ization. If the user sets a key that has not been `.initial`ized they will get an error message.

Comment: @A.Ellett (I have updated my answer after your edit. The `\par` seems—in this case—a better approach as you use `\raggedleft`. If you want to use ``\\``, you need to issue a `\noindent` at the start. This reduces the conditionals to two.) You can of course initialize the keys with a special macro (say `\pgfkeys@notset@by@user`) and test against that if an empty value is otherwise a valid input).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about PGF keys, but my idea would be to test whether the values are empty or not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\attrib}{m}{%
  \nopagebreak{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { ae/epigraph }
 {
  title .tl_set:N = \l_ae_epigraph_title_tl,
  title .initial:n = {},
  description .tl_set:N = \l_ae_epigraph_description_tl,
  description .initial:n = {},
  author .tl_set:N = \l_ae_epigraph_author_tl,
  author .initial:n = {},
  longestline .code:n = \ae_settowidth:n { #1 },
  afterskip .skip_set:N = \l_ae_epigraph_afterskip_skip,
  afterskip .initial:n = 1\baselineskip,
 }
\dim_new:N \l_ae_epigraph_longestline_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_ae_epigraph_longestline_dim { 3in }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ae_settowidth:n #1
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ae_epigraph_longestline_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
 }


\NewDocumentEnvironment{epigraph}{O{}}
  {
   \keys_set:nn { ae/epigraph } { #1 }
   \par\hspace*{\fill}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\dim_eval:n { \l_ae_epigraph_longestline_dim+1em } }
  }
  {
   \par
   \group_begin:
   \raggedleft\footnotesize
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_ae_epigraph_title_tl
    { \l_ae_epigraph_title_tl \\ }
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_ae_epigraph_description_tl
    { \l_ae_epigraph_description_tl \\ }
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_ae_epigraph_author_tl
    { \l_ae_epigraph_author_tl \\ }
   \vspace{-\prevdepth}
   \group_end:
   \vspace{1ex}
   \hrule
   \end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{\fill}%
   \vspace{\l_ae_epigraph_afterskip_skip}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{epigraph}[
  title={title},
  description={description},
  author={me},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 1
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}[
  author={me},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 2
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}[
  title={title},
  description={description},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 3
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}[
  title={title},
  description={description},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 4
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}[
  title={title},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 5
\end{epigraph}

\begin{epigraph}[
  description={description},
  longestline=abcdefghijklm
]
  Scenario 6
\end{epigraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution (as usual).  But, I don't understand how you're averting the application of `\\` when there's nothing else in the *list*.  I'm guessing that it has something to do with `\vspace{-\prevdepth}`, but I don't understand the mechanics of why this would work.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: The ``\\`` in `\raggedleft` issues `\par`; nothing special. The `\vspace{-\prevdepth}` is to ensure constant distance from the last baseline to the rule. Yes, the second `On` should have been `Off`