# How do you test whether a known key value has been set in pgfkeys

Tags: conditionals, pgfkeys

Using the `.code` handler to my keys and a private macro, I can easily test whether a key has been set when using `pgfkeys`.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mytestenvcounter}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\let\ae@mykey@test\relax
\def\ae@get@mykey@test{\ifx\ae@mykey@test\relax{I've not been set.}\else{I am set to:\ae@mykey@test}\fi}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/mykeys/set/.cd,
    mykey/.code = {\def\ae@mykey@test{#1}},
    /ae/mykeys/get/.cd,
    mykey/.code = {\ae@get@mykey@test},
  }
\makeatother
\newenvironment{mytestenv}[1]
  {\pgfkeys{ /ae/mykeys/set/.cd, #1}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}%
   \stepcounter{mytestenvcounter}\themytestenvcounter.)\hspace*{0.5em}
   \pgfkeys{ /ae/mykeys/get/mykey }%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \begin{mytestenv}{mykey={testing}}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{}
  \end{mytestenv}

\end{document}
```

But [in the comments to an earlier question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125051/22413) it was suggested that there's a better approach via `.initial` and testing for an empty value.  But, I don't know how to implement this.

This is as far as I know how to get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mytestenvcounter}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/mykeys/.cd,
    mykey/.initial=,
  }
\newenvironment{mytestenv}[1]
  {\pgfkeys{ /ae/mykeys/.cd, #1}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}%
   \stepcounter{mytestenvcounter}\themytestenvcounter.)\hspace*{0.5em}
   \pgfkeys{ /ae/mykeys/mykey }%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \begin{mytestenv}{mykey={testing}}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{}
  \end{mytestenv}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using `\pgfkeysifdefined`, but that always seems to test positve.

I've also seen [the following question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46107/22413), but don't understand how it relates to what I'm trying to do.  Additionally, in this particular question and answer, I don't understand why the need to `\detokenize` and the syntax for the definition of `\pgfkeysifstyleempty@i` seems incorrect.  So, if you're tempted to point me in that direction, I'd greatly appreaciate comments on what's happening there.

But, is it really necessary to define a macro to test for `empty` values in `pgfkeys`?  To be able to test whether a key has been set or not in the current environment seems to be something rather reasonable.  I've poured over the chapter on `pgfkeys` in the `tikz` manual.  But nothing there seems very promising, other than what I've already mentioned above.

Comment: I think this question is related: [How to detect if option provided via \tikzset](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101070)

Comment: I don't think that anymore. Instead of `\relax` (which might not be the ideal macro to check against [as we have learned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125051/is-there-a-way-to-define-starred-variants-for-a-keyvalue-system#comment280614_125072)) we can simply use `\pgfkeys@notset` we can check against. Best would be to create our own handlers for that and an own `\ifpgfkeyssetbyuser` for a better interface.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel why did you remove your solution?

Comment: The update I just edited in was wrong. Our solution do basically the same. The `pgfkeys` package uses a similar approach for testing for “no value given” (i.e. using a key without a =). I included a special version of the `-NoValue-` text from your `xparse` solution. One can still do `/.expand once=\pgfkeys@notset` but if a user uses this they should know what they do (or simply use `.unset`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a slightly simpler approach is sufficient for this via using `\empty` when it is not set and the value is in some macro when it is controlled by an `\if`. However it doesn't have to be `\empty`. Whatever the default value is you can test for it. It might not be a good idea to look for undefined macro for general error handling and debugging cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newcounter{mytestenvcounter}
\newif\ifaevalueisset
\pgfkeys{
/ae/mykeys/mykey/.code={\ifx#1\empty\else%
                             \aevalueissettrue
                             \edef\mytempval{\ignorespaces#1}% optional ignorespaces
                       \fi},
/ae/mykeys/mykey/.default=\empty,
}
\newenvironment{mytestenv}[1][]
  {\pgfkeys{/ae/mykeys/.cd,#1}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}%
   \stepcounter{mytestenvcounter}\themytestenvcounter.)\hspace*{0.5em}%
   \ifaevalueisset\mytempval\aevalueissetfalse\else\fi
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  }
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

  \begin{mytestenv}[mykey={testing}]
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}[mykey]a
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}[mykey=different combos]
  \end{mytestenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The following code provides the two handlers

- `.initial without value` and
- `.unset`.

Both set the key to the content of the `\pgfkeys@notset` macro which raises an error messge (or worse) if it is used anyway. (The `\pgfkeysvalueof` macro doesn’t check for a defined key.)

The `.initial without value` handler, much like the `.initial` handler, simply overwrites the key whereas the `.unset` key checks if the key is actual defined (more a handler for an user which should be able to “unset” keys).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfkeys@@notset{\PackageError{pgfkeys}
  {The \pgfkeyscurrentpath\space key has not been set to a value.}{}}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\Q=`\-
  \lccode`\N=`\N
  \lccode`\V=`\V
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def\pgfkeys@notset{QNoValue-\pgfkeys@@notset}}
\def\pgfkeys@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\pgfkeys@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{%
  .initial without value/.code/.expand once=%
    \expandafter\pgfkeyssetvalue\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfkeyscurrentpath\expandafter}\expandafter{\pgfkeys@notset},%
  .unset/.code=%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}
      {\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.initial without value}}
      {\PackageError{pgfkeys}
        {The \pgfkeyscurrentpath\space key has not been initialized.}{}}%
}
\def\ifpgfkeyssetbyuser#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname\pgfkeys@notset
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
\def\testkey#1{%
  \texttt{#1} is \ifpgfkeyssetbyuser{/#1}{set to ``\pgfkeysvalueof{/#1}''}{not set}.}
\begin{document}
% The \pgfkeyssetbyuser macro doesn't test
% whether the key it is actually defined, this results in "\relax"
\testkey{test} (\texttt{\char`\\relax})

\pgfkeys{test/.initial without value}
\testkey{test} % -> not set

\pgfkeys{test=1}
\testkey{test} % -> set to "1"

\pgfkeys{test=}
\testkey{test} % -> set to ""

\pgfkeys{test/.unset}
\testkey{test} % -> not set

\pgfkeys{test=-NoValue-}
\testkey{test}% -> set to "-NoValue-"

\pgfkeys{test/.unset}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/test} % -> "The /test key has not been set to a value."
                       % -> Output "-NoValue-"
\pgfkeys{testme/.unset}% -> "The /testme key has not been initialized."
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the command `\pgfkeysifdefined` to test if a key is defined. In order for it to work, you need to manually set the key with `\pgfkeyssetvalue`, which can be done automatically thanks to the key handler `.code`.

Be careful to add braces `{` and `}` around the macro to set the key locally as explained [in this answer about pgfkeys scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95355/19042).

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
  a/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{a}{#1}\pgfkeysgetvalue{a}{\a}},%
  b/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{b}{#1}\pgfkeysgetvalue{b}{\b}}}

\newcommand{\isDefined}[1][]{{% two braces to set the key locally
  \pgfkeys{#1}
  #1:\\
  \pgfkeysifdefined{a}{a is defined (a = \a)}{a is not defined}\\
  \pgfkeysifdefined{b}{b is defined (b = \b)}{b is not defined}}}

\begin{document}
  \isDefined[a=3]\smallskip\\
  \isDefined[b=2]\smallskip\\
  \isDefined[a]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

Considering the discussion with @Qrrbrbirlbel and how `xparse` handles undefined values, this is a solution I came up with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mytestenvcounter}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
%%----------
\begingroup
  \lccode`\Q=`\-
  \lccode`\N=`\N
  \lccode`\V=`\V
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def\ae@unset@key@value{QNoValue-}}
%%----------
\def\ae@set@keys{\pgfqkeys{/ae/my/test/keys}}
\def\ae@test@getvalue#1{\pgfkeysgetvalue{/ae/my/test/keys/#1}}
\ae@set@keys
  {%
    mytestkey/.initial/.expand once=\ae@unset@key@value,
  }
\newenvironment{mytestenv}[1]
  {\ae@set@keys{#1}%
   \begin{minipage}[t]{2in}%
   \stepcounter{mytestenvcounter}\themytestenvcounter.)\hspace*{0.5em}
   \ae@test@getvalue{mytestkey}\@mytestkey@value
   \ifx\@mytestkey@value\ae@unset@key@value
      {I've not been set:}\else
      {I have been set:}\fi\@mytestkey@value
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  }
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytestenv}{}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{mytestkey={testing}}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{mytestkey={-NoValue-}}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{mytestkey={QNoValue-}}
  \end{mytestenv}

  \begin{mytestenv}{}
  \end{mytestenv}

\end{document}
```

The idea here is to use `\lccode` values to create a value that is extremely unlikely to be passed to the key (unless someone else is also doing `\lccode` magic while using this environment).

[image]

Comment: The edit you made makes the same mistake as my previous version. It expands too much. Try: `\begin{mytestenv}{mytestkey={aa}}\end{mytestenv}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This is giving me such a headache.  :)

Comment: And by the way, the previous version could be easily tricked with `\makeatletter\begin{mytestenv}{mytestkey=\ae@unset@key@value}\end{mytestenv}\makeatother`. You actually need to protect `\ae@unset@key@value` and not the content of it (which is irrelevant).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's what I had noticed and was trying to circumvent.  I realized that all my `lccode`s were completely irrelevant to what I was testing.

Comment: At this point, I believe my solution is as fixed as it can be.  Even with `xparse`, if you really want you can trick `\IfNoValueTF` into believing you've passed nothing by a similar trick of changing `\lccode` and a appropriate peppering of `\expandafter`s.