# pgfkey `/.store in` handler not functioning as expected

Tags: pgfkeys, scoping

I'm still working on learning how to use `pgfkeys`.  Here's a snippet of code that I'm working on.  It compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys
  { /ae/polynomials/.cd,
    base/.initial = x,
    coefficients/.initial={3,5,2},
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\polynomial}{ O{}m } 
  {\pgfqkeys{/ae/polynomials}{coefficients={#2},#1}
   \ae@simple@polynomial
  }

\def\ae@simple@polynomial
  {\begingroup
     \pgfkeys
       {/ae/polynomials/.cd,
          coefficients/.get=\mycoefficients,
          base/.get=\myvar,
       }%%"
     %%\edef\mycoefficients{\pgfkeysvalueof{coefficients}}%%'
     \def\mydenominator{}%%'
     \def\myfraction{}%%'
     %% this next line is to assist in finding the degree of the polynomial
     \foreach \coef [count=\coefi] in \mycoefficients{}
     \edef\degree{\number\numexpr\coefi\relax}%%'
     \foreach \mytmpnumerator/\coef  [count=\coefi] in \mycoefficients%%'
       {%% find the degree of the current term in the polynomial
         \edef\degree{\number\numexpr\degree-\coefi\relax}
         %% determine whether there is a fracion present
         \ifx\mytmpnumerator\coef\else\def\myfraction{\frac}\def\mydenominator{\coef}\fi
         %% examine the coefficient
         \ifnum\coefi>1\relax
           \ifnum\mytmpnumerator<0\relax
             %% subtract the terms: reset numerator to a positive number
             -\edef\mytmpnumerator{\number\numexpr0-\mytmpnumerator\relax}%
           \else
             %% add the terms
             +\fi
         \fi
         %% print the coefficient
         \myfraction{\mytmpnumerator}{\mydenominator}
         %% print out the variables and their powers
         \ifcase\degree\relax
           \or
           \myvar\else
           \myvar^{\degree}
         \fi
         %%'
       } 
   \endgroup
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[
    \polynomial[coefficients={3,2,4/3}]{}
\]

\end{document}
```

Now in the `pgf` manual there is the following example:

```
\pgfkeys{/text/.store in=\mytext}
\def\a{world}
\pgfkeys{/text=Hello \a!}
\def\a{Gruffalo}
\mytext
```

which seems simple enough.  But when I rewrite my code to follow this example, I get errors.

My first attempt was to do something like this:

```
\def\ae@simple@polynomial
  {\begingroup
     \pgfkeys
       {/ae/polynomials/.cd,
          coefficients/.estore in=\mycoefficients,
          base/.estore in=\myvar,
       }%%'
....
<Remainder of definition is same as original MWE>
```

But this results in the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mycoefficients 

l.59     \polynomial[coefficients={3,2,4/3}]{}

?
```

This doesn't seem to match what the `pgf` manual suggests.

Nevertheless, I tried something else:

```
\def\ae@simple@polynomial
  {\begingroup
     \def\mycoefficients{}%%'
     \def\myvar{}%%'
     \pgfkeys
       {/ae/polynomials/.cd,
          coefficients/.estore in=\mycoefficients,
          base/.estore in=\myvar,
       }%%'
....
<Remainder of definition is same as original MWE>
```

This time I don't get an error, but `\pgfkeys` isn't storing my value in the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Now I was previously doing something like:

```
\edef\mycoefficients{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/polynomials/coefficients}}`
```

which will work.  But I wanted to be lazy and avoid having to write out the entire pathname for the key for each internal macro I'm trying to define.

Comment: The `.estore in` should be where the `.initial` was, yes? The `.get` stuff can be removed now. But why do you use `.(e)store in` either way? See [When to use a regular .initial key or a .store in key?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125197)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don't want the macros `\mycoefficients` etc. to have meaning outside of the definition of `\ae@simple@polynomial`.  So, I'm trying to localize the assignment.

Comment: Yes, the `.store in` doesn't do anything that defines the key as /.code=\def#1{##1}` (or `\edef` in the case of `.estore in`). So the macro `\myvars` and `\mycoefficients` will only be defined if you use the keys. So simply define `\polynomial` as `\begingroup <key settings> \ae@simply@polynom \endgroup`. (But then base is not defaulted, this only works perfectly if you use it globally or preset it in every `\polynomial` macro (not a good idea IMO).

Comment: You can defined `\def\polyvalueof#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/polynomials/#1}}`. But with `.get` you already get the shortest version where you don't need to provide the path at all. There is also `\pgfkeysgetvalue` (see my answer on the linked question) which does work with `\let` and not `\edef` (making it a little bit safer).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The problem with `.get` is whether I can get it first to expand its arguments.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But I'm still confused.  There seems to be a problem here between what the manual seems to suggest I can do and what is actually happening.  What am I doing that's not following the same idea as the manual?

Comment: When it is get or when it is set? For get: do an additional `\edef`. For set: `\coefficients/.expanded=<foo>`. Well you can't define the keys as `/.(e)store in` after you set them in `\polynomial`. That doesn't work, of course, you simply overwrite the key, the store is never done. (Do you mind reducing your MWE do something more clearly or move to chat?)

Comment: If you want to be lazy in that way, try defining, say, `\aepget = \pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/polynomials/#1}`.