# What is the correct way to get a pgfkey value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

This is my first foray into the pgfkeys package and I found the following behavior really odd. The Tikz/pgfkeys manual mentions two ways for setting key values: `\pgfkeys{key=value}` and `\pgfkeyssetvalue{key}{value}`. When I tried both, they return different values. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/my color/.initial = red, /my color/.estore in = \mycolor}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/my color=blue}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{yellow}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.

\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
The colors are blue and red.
The colors are blue and yellow.
```

I was expecting all blue on the first line and all yellow on the second. What went wrong?

Comment: Somehow, this problem has been extensively discussed in [What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129577/13304).

Comment: Simplified version can be `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfkeys}\begin{document}\pgfkeys{/my color/.initial = red}The color was \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color} but now; \pgfkeys{/my color=blue}the colors are\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}\pgfkeys{/my color=yellow}and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.\end{document}`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

My humble opinion is that the manual is misleadingly written here.  It freely mixes two different classes of `pgfkeys` operators:

- The *key-value* interface, which is accessed solely through the syntax `\pgfkeys{<key> = <value>}`, but which has extensible capabilities through the use (and creation!) of *handlers*, namely, special key suffixes that intervene in the processing of `<key>`.
- The *macro* interface, which consists of basically unrelated and unsophisticated commands such as `\pgfkeyssetvalue`.  These do *not* interact with handlers but rather access the internal TeX representation of keys directly; thus, they are super-fast by comparison with `\pgfkeys`, but don't participate in the high-level aspects of its language.

The next thing you have to understand is that a `<key>` in `pgfkeys` is actually an object consisting of several mangled TeX macro names, of which the two relevant ones here are

- `\pgfkeys@<key>`: the macro storing the *value* of `<key>`.
- `\pgfkeys@<key>/.@cmd`: the macro storing the *action* of `<key>`.

Finally, you have to understand how `\pgfkeys` decides what to do when it is presented with `<key> = <value>`:

1. It checks whether `<key>` has an action defined, and if so, executes it with `<value>` as its argument.
2. If not, it checks whether `<key>` has a value defined, and if so, replaces it with `<value>`.
3. If not, it checks whether `<key>` ends with the name of a known handler, and if so, executes it (with various context macros set so that the handler knows what to do with the rest of the key).

When you set up a key such as

```
\pgfkeys{/my color/.initial = red, /my color/.estore in = \mycolor}
```

what you have done is the following: set the *value* of `/my/color` to `red` and set the *action* of `/my color` to a macro defined, essentially, as

```
\pgfkeys@/my/color/.@cmd #1 -> \edef\mycolor{#1}
```

This is because `.estore in` is a handler that sets the action of the key requesting it.  `.initial` is also a handler, but it just sets the value of the key directly, rather than its action.

When you request the operations

```
\pgfkeys{/my color=blue}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.
```

you are asking `\pgfkeys` to access the *action* of `/my color`, which stores `blue` in `\mycolor` and *does not change* the value of `/my color`; thus, `\mycolor{} -> blue` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color} -> red` (still).

When you request the operations

```
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{yellow}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.
```

you are directly setting the value of `/my color`, bypassing the normal key-value processing, so that `\mycolor` is *not redefined* and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color} -> yellow`.  Now, expanding `\mycolor` should be an error, but you luckily put this line of code after the previous block that defined it to be `blue`, so it remains `blue`.  If you were to delete the first block then you'd get a TeX error about `\mycolor` being undefined.

Now, you may wonder how a key can have both a value and an action, if using `<key> = <value>` will only ever do the action if it exists.  The answer, as you have seen, is that you can always access the value with `\pgfkeysvalueof`, and also with handlers such as `.get`.  The equals sign, however, is a high-level operator and doesn't actually mean assignment: if you actually want to set a key value, you have to use `.initial` or `\pgfkeyssetvalue`.

My [personal opinion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125197/when-to-use-a-regular-initial-key-or-a-store-in-key/125225#125225) is that the macro operators should be avoided unless you are trying to mix `pgfkeys` with regular TeX code, in which case, obviously, the non-`pgfkeys` code has to use the macro interface.  If, however, you are using `\pgfkeys` exclusively and at a high level, then you should just go with handlers.  The only time within `pgfkeys` to use the macro operators is if you are writing the internals of a key: then the macros are likely faster than calling `\pgfkeys`, and also, if you avoid the use of the meta-equals sign, you will have better-defined behavior in the event that one of your keys gets it meta-behavior redefined behind your back.  (A really sneaky person could hack apart most `pgfkeys` code by redefining the handlers!)

Answer (score 8):

I would do it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/.cd, 
    my color/.store in = \mycolor,
    my color=red,}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{blue}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{yellow}\pgfkeysgetvalue{/my color}{\mycolor}
The colors are \mycolor{} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}.

\pgfkeys{my color=yellow} \pgfkeysgetvalue{/my color}{\mycolor}
\mycolor.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Above coloring is produced with:

```
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{blue}
The colors are \textcolor{\mycolor}{\mycolor} and \textcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}}.

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{yellow}\pgfkeysgetvalue{/my color}{\mycolor}
The colors are \textcolor{\mycolor}{\mycolor} and \textcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/my color}}.

\pgfkeys{my color=yellow} \pgfkeysgetvalue{/my color}{\mycolor}
\textcolor{\mycolor}{\mycolor}.
```

The `/.store` stores the value of key in a macro while key value can be different at later stage. To change the value of macro later you can either use `/.store` again or use `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/my color}{\mycolor}`. To change the value of key itself use `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/my color}{blue}`.

Comment: It seems to me that your `.cd` makes the use of `my color` in the following key-setting lines an error.

Comment: The third line in your first block of code contains a directory change that makes the following two lines set the key `/my color/my color`.