# What is the difference between "(no default, initially xxx)" and "(default xxx)" in the TikZ manual?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

This is not the first time I encounter this problem. Are there any differences between "(no default, initially xxx)" and "(default xxx)"? Thank you.

Comment: If my answer fulfills your request, consider to accept it please.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:Sorry, I have no experience with `tcolorbox` and I have not fully understood your explanation. Life is busy now. Please give me some time.

Comment: I just used `tcolorbox` as  a package that has `pgfkeys` and `tikz` syntax -- since you provided only a screen shot of code that does not compile for me, I switched to working code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `pgfkeys` documentation gives some clue: `.initial` is the value stored to the key at the time of definition, `.default` is the value that is used, if the user does not specify a value for the key

Example with `tcolorbox` (which uses `pgfkeys` and `tikz` in the backend)

The key `lower separated` is a boolean key, which is set to `true` in the beginning (initially), but it is sufficient to say `lower separated` only as the key, omitting `=true`, this way it is not necessary to remember the default value.

Now, the `colframe` key option is initially set to `black!75!white`, so this color will be used if `colframe` is not specified otherwise, but it has no default value, so just saying `colframe` is no valid syntax then.

The example from the O.P. does not compile for me, but `initially lineto` means that the key is set to `lineto` from the beginning and is used this way, but `no default` means, that it is not possible to say just `pre`, i.e a value must be specified with this key then.

We see the same behaviour in almost any `key-value` interface codes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[lower separated]

Foo

\tcblower

foobar
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To complement Christian's answer, it may help to distinguish "code keys" (which have a `/.code` handler) and "value keys" (which merely store a value). Indeed, a single key can be both (and more), but the key point is that the `/.default` handler takes care of *default arguments* for `/.code`handlers, while the `/.initial` handler takes care of the initial value (stored in `\pgfkeys@<key>` and accessed through e.g. `\pgfkeysvalueof` and `\pgfkeyssetvalue`). [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161982) may help to grasp the distinction.

Anyway, let us consider an example, with only `pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/code key with initial/.initial={initial value}, /code key with initial/.code={code key with initial(#1)}}
\pgfkeys{/code key with default/.default={default value}, /code key with default/.code={code key with default(#1)}}

\pgfkeys{/value key with initial/.initial={initial value}}
\pgfkeys{/value key with default/.default={default value}}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \pgfkeys{/code key with initial}
    % => code key with initial()
    \item \pgfkeys{/code key with default}
    % => code key with default(default value)
    \item \pgfkeys{/code key with initial=argument}
    % => code key with initial(argument)
    \item \pgfkeys{/code key with default=argument}
    % => code key with default(argument)
    \item \pgfkeysvalueof{/value key with initial}
    % => initial value
    \item \pgfkeysvalueof{/value key with default}
    % => (nothing!)
    \item \pgfkeyssetvalue{/value key with initial}{new value} \pgfkeysvalueof{/value key with initial}
    % => new value
    \item \pgfkeyssetvalue{/value key with default}{new value} \pgfkeysvalueof{/value key with default}
    % => new value
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

I defined two "code keys" so that they merely print their name and argument. When there is no argument, the *default* value is used instead (when defined) [and the initial value is not used at all]. When an argument is given, the default value is indeed not used.

Now, we can also use keys to store values, and retrieve them with `\pgfkeysvalueof` (among other possibilities). In this case, the value of the key is set to the value given to `/.initial` when the key is defined, as explained by Christian, and the default value has no effect.

Lastly, we could write a `/.code` handler for a key using the value of the *same* key, but then you enter a world of doom because you overload the default `\pgfkeys@<key>/.@cmd` (set by `/.code`) which would (temporarily! see the documentation of `/.initial` and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161982)) set the value of the key to something ...

Concerning your example, what the documentation calls a "default value" is in fact an initial value, as we can check on the source, `tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex`, where we find `/pgf/decoration/pre/.initial=lineto`. This key is used several lines after through `\pgfkeysvalueof`.
Here, using `pre=[something]` in tikz will modify the value of the key only locally (through the default handler) because everything is executed inside a group. We can reproduce this with a simple `pgfkeys` example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}

\def\pgfkeysingroup#1{
    \bgroup
    \pgfkeys{#1}
    \egroup
}

\pgfkeys{/val/.initial={initial}, /do/.code={val=\pgfkeysvalueof{/val}}}

\pgfkeysingroup{do}
% => val=initial
\pgfkeysingroup{val=argument,do}
% => val=argument
\pgfkeysingroup{do}
% => val=initial
\end{document}
```

Contrast with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/val/.initial={initial}, /do/.code={val=\pgfkeysvalueof{/val}}}

\pgfkeys{do}
% => val=initial
\pgfkeys{val=argument,do}
% => val=argument
\pgfkeys{do}
% => val=argument
\end{document}
```